# Make a WiX bootstrapper with CMake

Tags: wix, cmake, nsis, bootstrapper

I've successfully made an install package for my C++ application using the WiX generator provided by CMake.

Ideally, I'd like to install my dependencies (DirectX, MSVC++, etc) using a similar auto generated WiX bootstrapper.

Does anyone know of way to accomplish this?

I've tried using

```
INSTALL(CODE "exec_process(COMMAND <path to vcredist_x64.exe>)" COMPONENT vcppredist)
SET(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL application vcppredist)
```

This does not seem to work

If not WiX, is there a way to do this with the NSIS generator?